# add and remove id by pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove and add any id by pure JavaScript? Like

```
document.querySelector('div').classList.add('newClass') ;
```

and

```
document.querySelector('div').classList.remove('oldClass') ;
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 26):

Since ids are single strings it's just a matter of setting and unsetting it:

```
document.querySelector('div').id = 'whatever';
```

and to remove, just remove the attribute:

```
document.querySelector('div').removeAttribute('id');
```

Comment: `removeAttribute` is the way to go. Empty id attributes are not allowed (although it won't cause problems in any mainstream browser)

Comment: The `id` attribute must contain at least one character: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Edited answer to only reflect the proper usage

Comment: This is not the right answer. `removeAttribute` will remove the entire element, not just the attribute.

Comment: @6rchid it is correct. You can test it yourself or look at the MDN docs. You might be thinking of the `remove`  method which is the one to use to remove an element from the dom.

Answer (score 7):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this, to ***add*** new id:

```
document.querySelector('div').id = 'id_you_like';
document.querySelector('div').setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");
```

to ***remove*** the id attribute:

```
document.querySelector('div').removeAttribute('id');
document.querySelector('div').setAttribute("id", "");
```

Although you can set an empty(null) id for elements, it is **not** a good practice.

According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
> followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
> underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

If you use `jQuery`:

```
$('div').attr('id', 'id_you_like');
$('div').removeAttr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this,

```js
document.getElementById("before").id = "newid";
console.log(document.getElementById("newid").id)
//or
document.querySelector('div').id="newid"
```

```html
<div id="first">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To create an element an assign id

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'myId';
```

Or you can try if x is your element. set your attribute Id

```
x.setAttribute('id','myCoolElement')
```