# Can we add ID in pre existed div through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have access to html file, I can only edit my website through CSS or JavaScript. As my all pages of websites contain similar classes so in order to differentiate one page from other I want add ID or Class through JavaScript, I want to know that is it possible ?

Comment: You are right, actually I am embedding code from knack builder and they don't give access to html file.

Comment: Can you please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add and remove id by pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358737/add-and-remove-id-by-pure-javascript)

Comment: Yeah I want to add different background image on let say login page and white background colour on all other pages

Comment: Yes it is possible...

Comment: @dale landry  can you please  elaborate?

Comment: Add a class to the body tag based on the URL?  It really has nothing to do with the question, though.  Yes you can add an id to an element, but what id should you add, and to which element, something based again on the url?  Might as well use a class.

Comment: On each page for your body tag add the page name to the body, for example home would be <body id="home">, about would be <body id="about">, then in your css you can access particular class that is present across all page using `#home .nav { // specific styling for home nav element }` or  `#about .nav { // specific styling for about nav element }` using JS you could add these classes using `document.body.classList.add('specific-class')` then select them using a querySelector method.

Answer (score 1):

You must know the ID of the division for which you are adding a new class or changing the ID.

**To add a new Class into your Division**

`document.getElementById('your_div_id').classList.add('YourClass');`

**To add an ID to your div (Note: This will replace the previous ID of the div)**

```
var my_div = getElementById('your_div_id')
my_div.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");
```

EDIT: To get element by ClassName and make changes in it, you can do this,

```
var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass");
my_div[0].setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");
```

*This will only change the ID of the first div element with "yourClass" class*

Comment: But I want to add new ID , don't want to change already existed one.

Comment: @RamshaYounis it is not possible to have multiple IDs for one div (or element). So you can not have two IDs for one div. What you can do however is attach a new class to your div and use that newly added class to make changes for that specific element.

Comment: Actually where I want to add new id it only have class, so no pre existed id .

Comment: @RamshaYounis In that case, you may get the element by its class name. Check my edited post, I have added the code for that. Please note that when trying to get the element by class name, it actually returns collection of all the elements with that class name. So you will need to use index number to tell which element (div, in your case) you need to make changes in. If it is the first div, use "0" as index number like I have done.

Comment: As I said that initial code for all pages is same , like they have same classes , so if I will access through getElementsByClassName then it will be implemented to all other pages too.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding the Id By JS**

```
var div = document.querySelector(".class");
div.id = "id";
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".class");
div.id = "id";

alert(document.getElementById("id").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class=class>zXxz</div>
```

**Adding a class by JS**

```
var div = document.getElementById("id");
div.classList.add("class");
```

```js
var div = document.getElementById("id");
div.classList.add("class");

alert(document.querySelector(".class").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id=id>zXxz</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its possible, you can use the querySelector method to get de DOM reference and after this you can use de setAttribute() method to set the ID to an element.

Comment: there's no need to use `.setAttribute` - just set the `.id` property.